# Python 3: Creating A Function For User Choice

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to create a piece of code in Python 3 which allows the user to choose between several options. I have tried this several ways but none of them seem the right method to do so.

Example Attempt:

```
usr_input = input("Input: ")
while (usr_input != '1') | (usr_input != '2'):
    if usr_input == '1':
        search()
    elif usr_input == '2':
        sys.exit()
```

The problem with this is that the script hangs after entering an incorrect command.

Can anyone give me the correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you think the `|` operator does?  Have you tried it at the `>>>` prompt to see?  Please try and and then post your explanation for how the expression `(usr_input != '1') | (usr_input != '2')` is supposed to work.  It's important to explain your reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

Firstly, you only get `usr_input` once, outside the loop. If it's not a correct choice, you don't give the user the change to correct their choice: you simply loop. You'll need to do the `input` within the loop.

Secondly, your boolean condition is wrong. It is the equivalent of saying "x is not a OR not b", which is **always** true, since even if it is `a` it is still not `b`. A better way of saying it is `not in ['1', '2']`.

Putting these together:

```
usr_input = ''
while usr_input not in ['1', '2']:
    usr_input = input("Input: ")
    ... etc...
```

Comment: I prefer the `not in list` mode as well.

Comment: Is there a reason to use the `not in list` method as opposed to the one suggested by @orangeoctopus or is it just personal preference?

Comment: It's nice because you don't have to type usr_input more than once and scales to more options, like `['1', '2', '3', '4']`. I just feel like it is more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the while loop to keep asking for input when the user didn't input something properly. Inside of you while loop, usr_input never changes, so it just keeps looping.

You also have another issue: you should keep looping only if usr_input is not 1 AND is not 2. not 1 or not 2 is always true (if it is 2, it is not 1, and if it is 1 it is not 2).

```
usr_input = input("Input: ")
while (usr_input != '1') and (usr_input != '2'):
    usr_input = input("Input: ")

if usr_input == '1':
    search()
elif usr_input == '2':
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: The first time you ask for input doesn't actually do anything here, so shouldn't it just be left out and replaced with `usr_input = 0` so that the while loop doesn't reference something that as yet has no value?

Comment: (usr_input != '1') or (usr_input != '2') is always true, should be 'and' there

Comment: if you type in "1" first, it will never enter the while loop. Thanks for the catch Adrian, fixed.

Comment: Oh, I see! I thought the if statements were in the while loop at first glance. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`input()` performs the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`, so if your user inputs something syntactically incorrect, it will throw a SyntaxError exception. See the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input

You could improve your code by catching the SyntaxError and handling it, so it doesn't crash your program.

Comment: This is Python 3, where that isn't true.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I admit my experience is pre-Python 3 - which bit isn't true? `eval()`'s behaviour or catching Exceptions?

Comment: @KarlBarker in 3.x `input` only reads the string and strips the newline. No `eval()` is done.