# how to make the user choose between options

Tags: python

I make  password genrator using python then the teacher told to create a code that make the user choose what he want in the password
the password contains
1- lower case characters
2- upper case characters
3- numbers
4- punticuation marks

the teacher want me  to make the user choose if he want punticution or not
if he dont want it have to be deleted from the password
i tried so hard but i got stuck

```
from msilib import change_sequence
import string   
import random  # I import this line to  make the password unorgnaized

# this code below is all the characters we need for the password
s1 = list(string.ascii_lowercase)  
s2 = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
s3 = list(string.digits)
s4 = list(string.punctuation)

# this code is for the user to put how much characters he need
characters_number = input("how many characters for the password?:") 




# this while loop code is to make the user choose only 6 characters and up
while True:  
    try:                                                                                          
                                                                                                            
        characters_number = int(characters_number)
        if characters_number < 6 :
            print("you need at least 6 characters") # if the user choose an letter or digits it will not allow him
            characters_number = input("please enter the number again:")
                 
        else:
            break # I break the loop here if the user write the correct data 
          
    except: #this code here if the user enter anything except numbers
        print("please enter numbers only")
        characters_number = input("how many characters for the password?:")

# the random and shuffle is to make the password unorgnized            
random.shuffle(s1)
random.shuffle(s2)
random.shuffle(s3)
random.shuffle(s4)

# the password that will appear to the user it contains upper and lower letters, numbers and digit
# part1 here is for the letters I allocated 30% of the password for letters 
# part2 here is for the digits and numbers I allocated 20% of the password for letters
part1 = round(characters_number * (30/100))
part2 = round(characters_number * (20/100))

password = []

for x in range(part1):
    password.append(s1[x])
    password.append(s2[x])
    #the for loops here here is to create the password
for x in range(part2):
    password.append(s3[x])
    password.append(s4[x])


#this code here is to transform the password for list method to a string
password = "".join(password[0:]) 

print(password)
```

Comment: What (sub)problem are you specifically stuck at?

Comment: the teacher want me to make the user choose if he want punticution marks or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: Creating A Function For User Choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444127/python-3-creating-a-function-for-user-choice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function like this:

```py
def isUserNeedPunctuationMarks():
    result = None
    while True:
        inp = input("Do you need punctuation marks in your password? (y/n)")
        inp = inp.lower()
        if inp == "y":
            result = True
            break
        elif inp == "n":
            result == False
            break
        else:
            print("You must enter y or n")
    
    return result
```

The above function will return `True` if the user needs punctuation marks, and `False` otherwise. User has to type `y` (for yes) or `n`(for no).

You can call `isUserNeedPunctuationMarks()` in the right place in your code. For example, removing punctuation marks from `password` string, you have to write a condition like this:

```py
import re

if not isUserNeedPunctuationMarks():
    password = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', password) # This removes punctuation marks from a string using regex
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your response  but i think you dont understand me    The teacher want me to make the user choose if he want punticution or not  .the password will contain every thing but for the punticuation marks i want to ask him if he wnted or not

Comment: Sorry for that. I updated the answer... Comment if you need more information or if I still don't understand you. Accept it if it is helpful :) @BILALBSA

Comment: it worked but when i write n (no) it does not remove the punticuation marks

Comment: I wrote that function for asking the user for a choice; not for removing punctuation marks from a string (password). I didn't write that because you don't have asked it in your question. It was 'how to make the user choose between options' , not 'How to remove punctuation marks from a string'. I recommend you edit your post.

Comment: Anyway, I updated my answer to it. Hope it helps.